# Reverse Proxy works but not Virtual Host in the secondary RPi Web Server

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi3, reverse-proxy, virtualhost, lamp

I have two RPi(3+), both use for LAMP web server. And their relation is like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42eJw.png)

So, Rpi1 is the one directly talks to my home router and I set up reverse proxy to retrieve RPi2 Data.

My problem is I was able to access both RPi1 sites with their domains (static1.com and wordpress1.com) but both of RPi2 domains(static2.com and wordpress2.com) lead to the same site(wordpress2.com).

I assume my virtual host setting in RPi2 has some problem but could not find any clue yet... I need help solving this apache setting issue!

Here is my set up in RPi 1 Apache server,

static2.com setting:

```sh
pi@cloelee:/etc/apache2/sites-available $ cat static2.com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName static2.com
    ServerAlias www.static2.com
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.18/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.18/
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName static2.com
    ServerAlias www.static2.com
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.18/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.18/
    ProxyPreserveHost Off

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/static2.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/static2.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

wordpress2.com setting:

```sh
pi@cloelee:/etc/apache2/sites-available $ cat wordpress2.com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName wordpress2.com
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.18/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.18/
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName wordpress2
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.18/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.18/
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my setup in RPi2 Apache Server,

static2.com setting:

```sh
pi@kyongoh:/etc/apache2/sites-available $ cat static2.com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName static2.com
    ServerAlias www.static2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/static2.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?static2\.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://static2.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
</VirtualHost>
```

```sh
pi@kyongoh:/etc/apache2/sites-available $ cat static2.com-le-ssl.conf
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName static2.com
    ServerAlias www.static2.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/static2.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/static2.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

wordpress2.com setting:

```sh
pi@kyongoh:/etc/apache2/sites-available $ cat wordpress2.com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory "/var/www/wordpress2.com">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ServerName wordpress2.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@local_wordpress
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress2.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName wordpress2.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@local_wordpress
     DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

As you may realize wordpress2.com has not SSL yet but static2.com has. Do you see why both RP2 domains request wordpress2 data? what did I miss?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

It was simple fix, just missed to turn ProxyPreserveHost on

```
ProxyPreserveHost Off
```

to

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```